# JavaScript UTF-8 encoding issue with Danish string

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

Got a long string I want to turn into a downloadable fine. It has danish characters which get translated either as � or as ï¿½ depending if I try to alter the encoding or not.

this is my code:

```
    function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf8,'+text);
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  //element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

I've tried to both encode and decode the text, I've tried to put at charset : utf8, utf-8, iso-8859-1. Same result. Suggestions?

Comment: You should never need to use these `encode_utf8` and `decode_utf8` functions as long as you always properly set your content types. Are you calling them anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String.fromCharCode()** instead of the character.  For example **230** is equivalent to **æ**  **Æ** is equivalent to **Æ**, etc.

```
element.setAttribute('href', `http://www.Tr${String.fromCharCode(230)}kogslip.dk`);
```

My use case involved setting text involving fine-upload

```
 document.querySelector(".qq-uploader-selector").setAttribute("qq-drop-area-text", `Tr${String.fromCharCode(230)}k og slip filer her`);
```

You can use this site [toptal](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/letters/) as a reference to find HTML character codes.